# MS Excel, average values by multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I would like to ask if there's a possibility how output another table, which would contain following:

- take each person (column NAME) and make average time spent on the job (column TIME) and distinguish wether it was on A01 or A02 (column CAUS).

[image: Example here]

Thanks

Comment: Look into `AverageIfs()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the columns of the Output Table, copy the source NAME and CAUS columns to another location, and then Remove Duplicates across both columns. After doing this, you should have every unique NAME CAUS pair.

Next, use the [averageifs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690) function to get the average time.

> Syntax AVERAGEIFS(average_range, criteria_range1, criteria1,
>   [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
>
> The AVERAGEIFS function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> Average_range    Required. One or more cells to average, including
>   numbers or names, arrays, or references that contain numbers.
>
> Criteria_range1, criteria_range2, …    Criteria_range1 is required,
>   subsequent criteria_ranges are optional. 1 to 127 ranges in which to
>   evaluate the associated criteria.
>
> Criteria1, criteria2, ...    Criteria1 is required, subsequent
>   criteria are optional. 1 to 127 criteria in the form of a number,
>   expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells will be
>   averaged. For example, criteria can be expressed as 32, "32", ">32",
>   "apples", or B4.

[image]

[image]